# Poor scroll performance with UICollectionView - Profiling points to accessibility call

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, scroll, uicollectionview

In our app, we use a customized UIViewController managing a UICollectionView for loading a stream of messages. However, we noticed poor scroll performance. On time profiling, we noticed that [UICollectionView dequeReusableCell..] call takes over 35% of the time, most of which is due to a UICollectionViewAccessibility call.

Instruments Time Profiler snapshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLB49.png

Has anyone experienced similar problems before collection view? This was on an iOS8.1 iPhone 5s simulator with Accessibility options turned off.

Comment: Please show us  (id)dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath implementation so that we can find out if there is any modification or fix.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest limiting the number of accessibility items on the cell. Typical a cell should have 1 accessibility action that tells the user that they can select the cell to drill into more information about that item. If you're trying to make all the subviews in the cell accessibility items, that can cause an inordinate amount of time to be consumed in the dequeue.